# why i am getting this error while installing node js

Tags: node.js

[This is the Error i got at the end while installing node js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4WV2.jpg)
while installing node JS it was suppose to install some tools like chocolatye and few others please help me out to resolve this issue

Comment: Can you share more information when it occurs? Which node version are you trying to install?

Comment: @mahendra: Please avoid external links and images while asking questions.. it is better to ask questions that has the error message, explanation to what you are doing and other details 
read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask better question

Comment: I am trying to install node js Version--node -v13.14.0-x64 for my windows 7 . In fact node js  is installed but the additional tools which were supposed to install automatically in last step ,there i am getting this error . I think this is causing issue while writing javascript in VS code

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to install node, or chocolatye?

Comment: I have installed node js in windows 7 . At last it was supposed to install few tolls automatically but instead it is showing error

Comment: Can installing chocolatye help me solve the problem .

Comment: if you type in `node --version` into your terminal what do you get?

Comment: ```v13.14.0``` This is what i am getting and i am using windows 7